# apt cannot find ros package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to setup ros on a Pandaboard, running Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-1412-omap4 armv7l).  After running `apt-get update` I cannot install anything about ros, because apt cannont find any package starting with ros:

```
vision@panda-vis-01:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-ros-comm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-ros-comm
```

Y've set the repository to universe and multiuniverse, but still the same problem. Please help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76693/apt-cannot-find-ros-package/) by [rosmat88](https://answers.ros.org/users/6418/rosmat88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fuerte is not supported on Ubuntu Precise 12.04 http://wiki.ros.org/fuerte

You will need to use groovy or hydro.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-09-05**:
In the link says: "ROS Fuerte Turtle is primarily targeted at the Ubuntu Lucid, Oneiric, and Precise releases [...]". Is that wrong?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-09-05**:
Sorry I was too quick. You're right it is supported for precise. The issue you have is that you are running on armv7 there are only i386 and amd64 builds on the farm.